# How to set a URL alias for a custom entity type generated with drush?

Tags: entities, 9

I created a custom content entity type with the command `drush generate entity:content`.  Now I want to set a URL alias pattern at `/admin/config/search/path/patterns`, but my new custom content entity type is not available.  How can I add URL aliases to this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom entity type needs to have a `path` base field.

You can add it to `/src/MyEntity.php` in the `baseFieldDefinitions()` function:

```
$fields['path'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('path')
  ->setLabel(t('URL alias'))
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'path',
    'weight' => 30,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setComputed(TRUE);
```

Note that you need to uninstall the module containing the entity definition, make this change, and then re-enable the module, or run a database query to avoid messing up your DB.

Reference: [Discussion on changing the way this is handled in core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3055349)